# Laravel with postgresql, store and get binary data

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, download, binary

How to store and get data from postgres bytea field with Laravel ?
I want to update binary data and download them.
File types is jpg, excel, txt and so on.
Can I do?

currently my code to store.

```
    public function store_db( $file, $file_name, $user_id ) {

    $file_path = $file->getRealPath();

    $new_attachment = Attachment::create([
        'name' => $file_name,
        'mime' => $file->getClientMimeType(),
        'size' => $file->getClientSize(),
        'uploaded_data' => pg_escape_bytea(file_get_contents($file_path)),
        'created_by' => $user_id,
        'updated_by'=> $user_id,
        'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now()
    ]);

    return $new_attachment->id;
```

next to get and download data (jpg, excel, and so on)

```
    public function get_attachment( $id ) {
    $file = $this->attachmentRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

    $dbh = DB::connection()->getPdo();

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, mime, trim(trailing from encode(uploaded_data,'escape')) AS encode_data FROM attachments WHERE attachments.id = :atid");
    $stmt->bindParam(':atid', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch($dbh::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $name = $result['name'];
    $mime = $result['mime'];
    $headers = array(
        "Content-Type: {$mime}",
    );
    $fileData = $result['encode_data'];

    $ext = substr($name, strrpos($name, '.') + 1);
    file_put_contents($ext , pg_unescape_bytea($fileData));


    return response()->download($ext, $name, $headers);
```

Comment: You're doing too much manual work. Does eloquent not take care of the prepared statements for you ?

Comment: you are right. but how do i get bytea data from postgresql by laravel eloquent?

Comment: Seems that laravel doesn't support it out of the box but you could probably use a mutator like in e.g. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators

Answer (score 1):

Part of your code was useful for myself with Laravel 7. Here my solution 100% functional for me. I'm still waiting that it will be  of help you. Sorry for my english isn't my mother language.

```
        $dbh = DB::connection()->getPdo();
        $query = "SELECT *, trim(trailing from encode(uploaded_data,'base64')) AS encode_data FROM esq_inversion.view_documento_proyecto WHERE id = :id";
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $data = $stmt->execute();
        // Convert to binary and send to the browser
        $stream = base64_decode($data['encode_data']);

        return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($stream){
            $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
            fwrite($file, $stream);
            fclose($file);
        }, $fileName,[
            'Content-Type' => $mime,
            'Cache-Control' => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment;filename*=UTF-8\'\'' . $fileName.'";',
            'Expires' => '0',
            'Pragma' => 'public',
        ], 'attachment');
```

Best regards, Migue

Answer (score 0):

For me, all the files I was restoring from the database was corrupted. Then I found that the `pg_escape_bytea()` is returning everywhere instead of one apostrophe -> two.
So I use `str_replace` when storing the binary data and that solve the problem:

```
File::create([
 'report_id' => $report->id,
 'name' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
 'mime' => $file->getClientMimeType(),
 'size' => $file->getSize(),
 'data' =>  str_replace("''", "'", pg_escape_bytea(file_get_contents($file_path))),
 'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
 'updated_at' => Carbon::now()
]);
```

Then my method for downloading the files:

```
public function fileDownload(File $file)
    {
        file_put_contents($file->name , stream_get_contents($file->data));

        $headers = array(
            "Content-Type: {$file->mime}",
            "Content-Length: {$file->size}"
        );

        return response()->download($file->name, $file->name, $headers)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
    }
```